# Ajax call breaks binding to object children

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Without the ajax call, My main view binds to my parent class and the partial view on main view, binds to a child member of the parent class

parent...

```
public class Client
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(120)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // etc...

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

child of parent...

```
public class Address
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    // etc...

    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

}
```

the main view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-htci-target", "addressData" } }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            @Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(model => model.Name).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>

    @{ var vdd = new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Address" } };}

    @Html.Partial("_AddressPartial", Model.Address, @vdd)
```

// yada yada...you can imagine the rest of the very standard view

The partial view's model is Address and all hooks up.
When I post back to the server the Address member is properly filled with entered data from the partial view...

So now...in my partial view, I now load the js to call the async routine to load the IP GEO data for the user - so it pre-fills the city, province, country

Any example of an ajax call will suffice...mine calls an AddressControl, returns a partialview result and  replaces a div named addressData with the updated partialview :

```
$(function() {

var urlGeoIeoip = "http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?";

$.ajax({
    url: urlGeoIeoip,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (geoipdata) {


        $.ajax({
            url: "/getlocationdata/" + geoipdata.country + "/" + geoipdata.regionName + "/" + geoipdata.city,
            type: "GET",
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                //var $form = $(this);
               // var $target = $($form.attr("data-htci-target"));
                var $newHtml = $(data);
                //alert($target);
                $("#addressData").replaceWith($newHtml);
                $("#City").data("kendoComboBox").value(geoipdata.city);
                $("#State").data("kendoComboBox").value(geoipdata.regionName);
                $("#Country").data("kendoComboBox").value(geoipdata.country);
            }
        });


    }
}).fail(function(xhr, status) {
    if (status === "timeout") {
         // log timeout here
    }
});
});
```

All works great!

BUT

Now, when I post back to the user via the submit button, the Address child member of the parent class is null....

How do I get it to rebind the Address member of the parent class after return of the ajax call?

Comment: The name attribute of your address fields needs to be 'Address.City', 'Address.State' etc. If the names are just 'City' then the the model binder will look for the property City of the Client model which doesnt exist.

Comment: But the model for the partial view IS Address. Your suggestion would require the Address model to contain an Address member. This will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By generating your input fields in the partial view, the HTML helpers are unaware that your Address model is a property of your initial Client model, so it's generating HTML inputs like:

```
<input type="text" id="City" name="City" />
<input type="text" id="State" name="State" />
```

If your POST action method is accepting a Client model then the model binder will look for the properties City and State of the Client model, which don't exist.

You need your HTML input to look like:

```
<input type="text" id="Address_City" name="Address.City" />
<input type="text" id="Address_State" name="Address.State" />
```

Instead of using a partial for your Address fields, you should use an [Editor Template](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/) which will then preserve the parent property as you need in this case.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address)
```

Comment: The HTML will never look like that as the model for the Partial view is Address. It's the same as if it were the Parent class of Client. You suggest an Editor Template; so does that mean Partial Views can not be ever used for Child objects and we must always use Editor Templates?

Comment: Your HTML _is_ being generated as described in the answer. The jQuery selector `$("#City")` indicates that your code indeed is not taking into account that the `Address` model is a property of your `Client`. Partial Views cannot infer hierarchy of properties, which is generally not a problem unless you are collecting data to bind to a model. If you wanted to continue to use your partial view then pass the entire `Client` model to the partial view, otherwise, use the preferred method of an Editor Template.

Comment: Sorry - I misread - yes, I've verified that the fields are being generated as  id="Address_City" name="Address.City" so I'll update the script. I'll let you know.